# Not able to install "Sharp Module" in nodejs using npm

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

when i install Sharp Module using "npm install sharp" command. Occur some error please click below image you get some clarification

[image]

Comment: It looks like you need to install python or cyg-win

Comment: yes i installed python

Comment: how to interact with python and sharp??

Answer (score 0):

if you are on **windows** you can use the following

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

then install

```
npm install sharp
```

it takes sometime for installation but sharp is worth it :)

Answer (score 0):

Not found with Python 3.
You can force the use of python 2 (after installing it)

> node-gyp install --python C:\Python27